# Get current status from httptest (Zabbix)

Tags: monitoring, curl, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I'm trying to use PHP/CURL to query Zabbix and find whether a service is available or not.

From Zabbix Web interface, I get this screen, which shows the test and its status.

[Zabbix Web Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi50k.png)

I'd like to get this data (test name and status) as JSON in order to display in another application.

I'm posting the following JSON:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"httptest.get", "params": {"output":"extend"},"auth":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","id":0}'
```

Which returns the tests, but not its status.
What json request should I use in order to receive an status flag (Ok / NOk) ?

Answer (score 0):

That `OK/NOK` status for web monitoring is calculated by [frontend code](https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix/blob/e416e8a24120db593f373e76592d3fbbe7a306a3/frontends/php/include/classes/screens/CScreenHttpTest.php#L137-L158) and API method for that result is not available.

You should to use `item.get` to get web monitoring item value (for example item "lastfailedstep/Failed step of scenario ...") and then you should to calculate `OK/NOK` status in your code. See [Zabbix item.get API documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/reference/item/get) for the parameters.

Comment: Should I give an itemid as a parameter? How can I find this "itemid" ? Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain your comment more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Took me waaaay too long to figure this out.

You want to make a `item.get` request and fill out the `webitems` field in your query.

like `"webitems": "true"`

For example:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "item.get",
    "params": {
        "output": "extend",
        "sortfield": "name",
        "webitems": "true",
        "search": {
            "name": "Response code"
        }
    },
    "auth": "token",
    "id": 1
}
```

Then you'll be able to fetch `lastvalue` for the value, or even use `history.get` with the `itemid`.